# Spring for Android, XmlPullParserException: unresolved: &mdash;

Tags: java, android, spring, xml-parsing

I'm using some public API in my project, this API returns XML responce.

I'm using Spring for Android and Simple XML Serialization for rest calls and XML mapping.
Everything was going good, but one method can return text with some special characters (in my case —), so when I call this method I get exception:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read [class
>   com.MyMappingClass]; nested
>   exception is org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unresolved:
>   — (position:TEXT @14:214 in java.io.InputStreamReader@64d962b0)

In RestTemplate I'm using next HttpMessageConverter:

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
mediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter();
messageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
messageConverters.add(messageConverter);
```

In mapping class I have field, which has to contain got text:

```
@Element(name = "synopsis", required = false)
public String seriesSynopsis;
```

Detailed stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read [class com.MyMappingClass]; nested exception is org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unresolved: &mdash; (position:TEXT @14:214 in java.io.InputStreamReader@64d962b0)
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:115)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:76)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:655)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:415)

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unresolved: &mdash; (position:TEXT @14:214 in java.io.InputStreamReader@64d962b0)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.checkRelaxed(KXmlParser.java:302)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readEntity(KXmlParser.java:1275)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1392)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.read(PullReader.java:105)
at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.next(PullReader.java:89)
at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.peek(PullReader.java:72)
at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeReader.readValue(NodeReader.java:224)
at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.InputElement.getValue(InputElement.java:201)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Primitive.read(Primitive.java:163)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Primitive.readElement(Primitive.java:207)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Primitive.readElement(Primitive.java:189)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Primitive.read(Primitive.java:124)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.j
```

Also headers from resporce:

```
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →577
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I'm not so good with Spring, but can I somehow ignore special characters? 
Or how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think I resolved this issue, I wrote custom `XmlHttpMessageConverter`, which replaces all spec characters in `readInternal` method.

Comment: Also, I think I can save all secial characters, I found solution in this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287473/). I hope it will be helpful for somebody =)